# LINQ return 0 if query from DataTable is null

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

Hi Everyone I have the following query. On occasion, there are no results for this query, and I will need it to return a 0, rather than an error.

```
var count= dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("names").Equals(name) && x.Field<string>("port").Equals("true")).Count();
```

I have tried adding ?? 0 but the compiler doesn't like that.

thanks for the help!

Comment: `Count` doesn't throw an error if the sequence is empty, it returns 0. Do you instead mean that `dt` can be `null`?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Tim, sorry for the confusion. yes, the data table can from time have no records that match the query. my expectation would have been with the COUNT, that it would have come back 0 if there were no records. instead i get back a system.DBNull error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't throw an error if the sequence is empty, it returns 0. Do you instead mean that `dt` can be `null`? So either the `DataTable` is `null` or one of the strings is `null`. You don't need to use `String.Equals` you can use `==` to compare strings meaningfully, then you don't get an exception. You can also use this shorter way using the overload of `Count`:

```
if(dt == null) return 0;
return dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Count(x => x.Field<string>("names") == name && x.Field<string>("port") == "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var count=dt != null ? dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("names").Equals(name) && x.Field<string>("port").Equals("true")).Count() : 0;
```

It will simply check if dt is null before any operations on dt are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yoda comparison for handle case when you have null in database:

```
var count= dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => name.Equals(x.Field<string>("names")) 
                      && "true".Equals(x.Field<string>("port")))
             .Count();
```

[image]